# Python error trying to install smart_open

Tags: python

I'm trying to install some requirements on my python project, but it doesn't work.

This is what I have on my console:

```
pip install -r requiremnts.txt
```

But in the process I receive this message:

```bash
 Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in smart_open setup command: 'python_requires' must be a string containing valid version specifiers; Invalid specifier: '>=3.5.*'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you are using a package "smart_open" which used version constraints like `>=3.5.*` till version 5.1.0 of the package, there was a [GitHub issue #638](https://github.com/piskvorky/smart_open/issues/638) on their repository which was then resolved from version 5.2.0 onwards. So you need to upgrade the version of this package in your requirements to resolve this.